# Linux server, locating files containing nothing but 4 specific lines

Tags: linux, ssh, find, grep

I'm dealing with a compromised website, in which hackers injected an htaccess instruction to redirect traffic. I can easily locate .htaccess files that contain the forwarding hack, BUT in cases where the directory already contained an htaccess file, they appended the dangerous instructions, so I cannot just deleted any htaccess file or could harm the site by letting formerly pw-protected directories wide open, or urlrewrite instructions (WordPress) be deleted, etc.
I could not find the way to locate files that only contain those 4 lines of redirect hack, could you shed some light ?
So far, using

find . -type f -exec grep -q targetpiratedomain {} \; -exec echo rm {} \;

Thanks !

Comment: Just delete all .htaccess files and get the right ones from your source control system. After that you can concentrate on finding and closing the hole the hackers used.

Comment: Makes sense but in fact applies to several sites some of which created by others, hence not in our SVN - or installed from WordPress. Hence I thought it'd make much more sense to only delete files that contain nothing but the hack, then locate those to edit manually.

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the .htaccess files as template. Then issue the following command:

```
find . -type f -name .htaccess -exec cmp -s <template> {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

`cmp` will compare the file to the template file and if this returns true, the `rm` is executed. You might want to test this first with `echo` or `cat` instead of `rm`.

Be sure to rename or move the template file before starting the command, else the template will be removed during the process.

Comment: Wonderful, I could fix the issue based on this :

find . -type f -name .htaccess -exec cmp -s /home/referencetpl {} \; -exec rm {} \;

best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the size of the .htaccess file - all the simple ones should be the same size?
You should also restrict your find command to only include files with the right name.

Also, as in the comments, what you should really do, is just restore the site from source control.

Comment: Testing the size is a good idea. Unfortunately all files are called .htaccess, only what they contain may differ. Source control is fine for developed sites, but most here are CMS so data is not versioned, hence removing the faulty files would be much faster than full-sites restoring, as the security issue was elsewhere on the (Plesk) server.